# Cannot proceed to checkout from cart after installing 1.8

Tags: checkout, cart, php, onepage-checkout

i have recently upgraded to magento 1.8.1 and since that point if i have my SSL enabled on the front end my customers cant proceed to the checkout from the cart. When the button is clicked the cart just gets reloaded.

After doing some research some people said it was suhosin php causing the problem. Well i had that disabled by my hosting providers, cleared store and browser cache etc but yet the problem stilll persists.

has anyone else had this problem?

If so how did you solve it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

When i enter the site using https:// and SSL is turned ON in front end, i can proceed to checkout fine from the cart.

When i enter the site from http:// and SSL is turned OFF i can proceed to checkout fine from the cart.

The problem is occurring when i enter the site via http:// and have SSL turned ON in front end. SO it seems that data isn't being transferred from http and https:// or something

Comment: Is there something in `magento/var/log` files?

Comment: I dont seem to have a logs directory in var?

Comment: Have you enabled `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and developers mode in index.php?

Comment: no i have not, i do know about the ini_set method but wasnt sure how to do it in magento?

Comment: just go to index php. Uncomment line `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and comment if statement around `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);`.

Comment: i have just done what you said but no logs are showing unfortunately or any errors in console or the logs. I have added an update above with more information

Answer (score 1):

I can explain you that.

When SSL is turned ON magento thinks that your site is available only from https(and this is logically). So if customer click to "Checkout" button on http site it redirects you to https checkout page but browser permission does not allow to access http domain cookies data from https domain. The only way to fix that configure your server to redirect customer to https domain when he tries to access http one.

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Would this be something i have to contact my server providers about or something i can do myself? i have access to cpanel and that is all. Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `Base URL` in `System->Configuration->Web->Secure`? Does it contain https?